# Javascript regex - check if string contains two or more of same letter

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm working on some regex with JavaScript. I have now created a regex that checks if a string has two or more of the same letter following each other. I would want to create a regex that checks if a word / string contains two or more of one particular letter, no matter if they are after each other or just in the same word / string.

It would need to match: **drama** and **anaconda**, but not match: **lame**, **kiwi** or **tree**.

This is the regex in JS.

```
const str = "anaconda"; 
str.match(/[a]{2,}/);
```

Comment: Maybe all you need is `/a.*a/` (or `/a[^a]*a/`) to test if a string contains at least two `a`s?

Comment: Something like `\S*(\S)\S*\1\S*` https://regex101.com/r/VNnfjP/1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```js
\w*(\w)\w*\1\w*
```

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/omh2Yb/1)

**EXPLANATION**

```js
NODE                     EXPLANATION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \w*                      word characters (a-z, A-Z, 0-9, _) (0 or
                           more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \w                       word characters (a-z, A-Z, 0-9, _)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \w*                      word characters (a-z, A-Z, 0-9, _) (0 or
                           more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \1                       what was matched by capture \1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \w*                      word characters (a-z, A-Z, 0-9, _) (0 or
                           more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
```

Comment: Yes for word characters I think this would be it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, with great explanation! But in this case the regex would match for example the word: **tree** and **kiwi**, and I only want the match to happen if the word in question has two or more: As in the given string. Any input on this issue?

Comment: Could this be a solution: ```[a]*([a])\w*\1[a]*``` ?

Comment: @Krullmizter [Not quite](https://regex101.com/r/omh2Yb/2).

Answer (score 0):

My thought process was something like this:

1. A word can start with any Alphabet
2. A word can end with any Alphabet
3. Similar letters can have zero or multiple alphabets between them
4. If any of it's letters are similar and it fits the criteria above then accept the word

```js
     regex = /[a-z]*([a-z])[a-z]*\1+[a-z]*/
```